# Angular inject property into $scope

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, scope

Is there a way to inject a property or function into $scope that will be passed along to every controller / other for use in the rest of the application? Something that could be set when we create the ng-app..

Comment: You should look for value, constant, service, factory and provider services.

Comment: Are you suggesting i create my own object to inject as opposed to injecting into $scope?

Comment: I found this article that seems to be what i am after http://pacho.me/post/54107137988/inject-value-in-angular-js-rootscope-after-manual

Comment: right since services can be reused throughout the application they are the best choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set 'global' properties with `$rootScope`. For example, after defining your app :

```
 app.run(function($rootScope) {
    return $rootScope.RESQUE = 'http://localhost:7999/resque/overview';
  });
```

You can then access this property in HTML with `{{RESQUE}}` .

You can also define constants with `.constant():`

```
angular.module("awesomeApp", []).constant('RESQUE', 'http://localhost:7999/resque/overview');
```

and then inject it in your controllers like any other dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and actually you can use whatever your want for that. But usually it makes most sense to use `.constant()` (for values that don't change) or `.value()` (injectable values that *could* change).

So you can do something like:

```
angular.module("myApp", []).constant('MY_FIX_VALUE', 5);

// and use it like this
angular.module("myApp").controller('FooCtrl', ['MY_FIX_VALUE', function (MY_FIX_VALUE) {

}]);
```

Comment: thanks @PascalPrecht but I am trying to add a bunch of reusable functions to either $rootScope or $scope so that i can access them all from any of my controllers, do you have an example of how i could do this without defining constants?

Comment: Sounds like a perfect use case for a service :)